# Searching for Title about immortal who can talk with intelligent appliances

Tags: story-identification, books, artificial-intelligence

I've spent the last hour trying to find a Science Fiction adventure series about a man, who I think is immortal, who escaped from a proscribed planet, and who goes around helping people. OK, so far, not very unique, eh?

The unique thing about this series is that this man can telepathically communicate with ALL of the appliances in civilization (toasters, refrigerators, doorbells, etc.) that are all run by 75th generation Z80 chips, (cheap as hell, but with advanced AI and sentience) who spend all their time quietly serving humans AND gossiping among themselves telepathically about their human patrons.

Can anybody tell me who the author is, AND the series, so I can find it at my local library system?

Comment: Do you remember when you read it or when it may have been published?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/214453/sci-fi-series-about-a-mercenary-with-a-spaceship-with-ai (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 5):

**Jon & Lobo** series by **[Mark L Van Name](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/n/mark-l-van-name/)**

1. **One Jump Ahead** (2007)

Jon Moore: A nanotech-enhanced warrior who wants nothing more than a quiet life and a way back to his strange home world. Lobo: An AI-enhanced Predator-Class Assault Vehicle, a mobile fortress equipped for any environment from the seabed to interstellar space. TWO WOLVES IN A GALAXY OF LARGER PREDATORS

Jon Moore wanted only to relax on the pristine planet of Macken--but Macken was the secret battleground of two megacorporations, both determined to control the local jump gate and the riches of an undeveloped world. Moore was too valuable a tool not to be used, whether or not he was willing. What the corporations didn't realize was that Moore had a mind of his own and a conscience that wouldn't let him quit until he'd righted the wrong they'd tricked him into making. And Moore had Lobo--or just possibly Lobo had Jon Moore, because this Assault Vehicle had a mind of its own. . . .

Finding allies and enemies among terrorist groups and elite mercenaries, gun-runners and the only kind of government possible on a frontier short on rules and long on riches, Jon and Lobo fight to a climax with a corporate army that can't afford to leave any witnesses. Exotic settings, fast action, real tech, mechanically-enhanced animals-and a beautiful woman who's as deadly as a cobra!

2. **Slanted Jack** (2008)
3. **Overthrowing Heaven** (2009)
4. **Children No More** (2010)
5. **No Going Back** (2012)